# GtkTreeView set selection to specific row

Tags: c, treeview, gtk, selection

How can I set the `GtkTreeSelection` to a specific row, to the row number `3`?

I can set the selection to the `GtkTreeIter`, but how can i set the `iter` to the row number `3`?

I didn't find anything useful at the google search, so I didn't try anything yet because I don't know what.

I hope you can help me and give me information about my questions!

EDIT:

```
GtkTreeModel *model = gtk_tree_view_get_model(GTK_TREE_VIEW(treeview));
GtkTreePath *path = gtk_tree_path_new_from_indices(3, -1);
gtk_tree_model_get_iter(model, &iter, path);
gtk_tree_path_free(path);
gtk_tree_selection_select_path(treeview_selection, path);
```

-> Don't work

Comment: You are using *path* after freeing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use a `GtkTreeIter` for this, the [`GtkTreePath`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTreeModel.html#gtk-tree-path-new-from-indices) API is enough. You're throwing your path away before using it, which creates problems.

Here's how to do it:

```
GtkTreePath *path = gtk_tree_path_new_from_indices(3, -1);
gtk_tree_selection_select_path(treeview_selection, path);
gtk_tree_path_free(path);
```

**UPDATE**: I rewrote the code completely to drop use of  `GtkTreeIter`, I originally thought that you wanted a solution using an iter since that was what you were trying to do.

If you just want to do a selection (and don't, for instance, need a `GtKTreeIter` for something else) the above is the simplest way using just a `GtkTreePath`.

Take care not do destroy the path before using it in the select-call, of course.

Comment: See my EDIT at the question

Comment: If the goal is to set selection to a row whose index is known in advance, why go through an iter? The OP's code in the question should work, only if it moved `gtk_tree_path_free()` *after* the call to `gtk_tree_selection_select_path`, right?

Comment: @user4815162342 Right. I rewrote to simplify. Thanks.