# How to Highlight GTKTreeView Row in C as if was selected with mouse

Tags: c, gtk, row, highlight

I've either looking too deep or or something. I have a simple GTKTreeVew that is populated from a file. The number of rows is determined by the number of lines in a CSV file.

I can get get data from each line in a loop, but can seem to grasp how to highlight the row. I can select it getting it's path and printf the row number, but don't know how to highlight it in code...

```
selection = gtk_tree_view_get_selection(GTK_TREE_VIEW(gtk_tree_view));
if (gtk_tree_selection_get_selected(selection, &model, &iter))
{
    path = gtk_tree_model_get_path (model, &iter);
    path_string = gtk_tree_path_to_string (path);
    row = atoi(path_string);
    set_active_test_row_single(row);

    printf("\nSelected ROW is %d\n", row);

}
```

Thanks for any links, feedback etc. Can't seem to find function to "highlight" the row number. The same "highlight" that happens when a row is clicked on with the mouse.

Comment: Maybe the snippet in [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40343004/change-selected-row-in-gtk-tree-selection-from-c-function) does what you want. Or maybe the answer to this one... [GtkTreeView set selection to specific row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26626140/gtktreeview-set-selection-to-specific-row)

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out with googleing for about a week and seeing other similar examples in other languages.

```
void single_button_clicked_cb(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data)
{
    static int         index = 0;
    GtkTreeIter iter;
    char buf[9];
    GtkTreeModel *model;
    GtkAdjustment *vadjustment;
    int i;

    printf("\nScroll Active test row to %d\n",index);

    sprintf(buf,"%d",index);

    gtk_widget_grab_focus (GTK_WIDGET(gtk_tree_view));

    GtkTreePath *path = gtk_tree_path_new_from_string(buf);

    gtk_tree_view_scroll_to_cell(GTK_TREE_VIEW (gtk_tree_view),path, NULL,FALSE, 0.0, 0.0);

    gtk_tree_view_set_cursor (gtk_tree_view,path,NULL,FALSE); // works but doesn't scroll

    gtk_tree_path_free(path);

    index++;
}
```